# Twitterでテキストと画像を一緒に投稿する

Tags: objective-c, twitter

現在以下のコードのようにしてTwitterにテキストを投稿させたのですが、画像の添付の仕方がわかりません。投稿のためのダイアログを表示させたくないので、`Social.framework`は使いたくないです。

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    NSString *encode = [GTMOAuthAuthentication encodedOAuthParameterForString:@"テストTweet http://www.yahoo.jp"];
    NSString *body = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"status=%@", encode];
    [request setHTTPBody:[body dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [auth_ authorizeRequest:request];

    GTMHTTPFetcher *fetcher = [GTMHTTPFetcher fetcherWithRequest:request];
    [fetcher beginFetchWithDelegate:self didFinishSelector:@selector(postTwitterFetcher:finishedWithData:error:)];
```

やり方を調べてみても、次のサイトのようなとても長いコードのやり方しか載っておらず、処理の把握ができません。
https://twittercommunity.com/t/how-to-post-image-to-twitter-by-using-http-upload-twitter-com-1-statuses-update-with-media-for-below-ios-5-0/6290 
どうすればTwitterに画像とテキストを一緒に投稿することができるでしょうか？
どなたか分かる方がいればご教授いただきたいです。
すみませんが、宜しくお願いします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TwitterAPIで、画像とテキストを同時に送信することは出来ません。

https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/statuses/update
パラメータの説明に"media_ids"というのが存在しますので。IDを渡す必要があります。

このIDは、どこから入手するかというと。そのオプションの説明からリンクが貼られている
https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/uploading-media
から取得します。

つまり
1. 画像をアップロードする。 (POST media/upload)
2. 画像のIDを付けて、ツイートする。(POST statuses/update)
と2度の処理が必要になります。

参考にされているtwittercommunity.comの投稿では、
POST statuses/update_with_media を利用して、一度に処理していますが。
残念ながら現在はdeprecatedに指定されています。
https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/statuses/update_with_media

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。TwitterAPIでは画像とテキストは同時に送信できないのですね。ご提示いただいた方法を参考にプログラムを組んでみたいと思います。一歩先に進めそうです。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

social.frameworkを使うお考えはありませんか？？
social.frameworkはアップルが標準で用意してくれているフレームワークの１つです。

Frameworkをインポートしてあげて、ソーシャル用のViewController(SLComposeViewController)を呼び出してあげれば、テキストに画像をつけることができます。

```
　　SLComposeViewController *vc = [SLComposeViewController
              composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];

    [vc setInitialText:self.postFormat];
    [vc addImage:self.sharingImage];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
Social.frameworkを使うと標準のダイアログを使用して投稿しなければならないので、Social.frameworkを使わない実装をしたいです。